# Has SNL had any writer on to perform beside William S. Burroughs?

Tags: saturday-night-live

[This New Yorker article](https://www.newyorker.com/magazine/2014/02/03/the-outlaw-2) entitled ***The Outlaw*** The extraordinary life of William S. Burroughs wrote:

> But Burroughs liked his own growing fame. He gave readings to full houses. Appearances on “Saturday Night Live,” in 1981, and in Gus Van Sant’s “Drugstore Cowboy,” in 1989, spread the popularity of his gentleman-junkie cool.

[This YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ye0Zp9J6Z30) entitled *Guest Performer: William S. Burroughs - Saturday Night Live* has the entire recording of his performance.

I've never seen a writer on SNL as the "guest performer". [Ranker](https://www.google.ch/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=16&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiG_5evj4LZAhWHWhQKHUy-ApAQFgh4MA8&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.ranker.com%2Flist%2Fsnl-musical-guest-list%2Franker-music&usg=AOvVaw2h9W3BMRPlPl2oCSsGY0uz) mentions:

> Since its premiere in 1975, SNL has had more than 600 unique musical guests.

Most "guest performer"s are usually musical in nature.

Besides William S. Burroughs has any writer been on SNL as the "guest performer"?

Comment: I'd suggest you look for yourself since a complete list is available - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Saturday_Night_Live_guests

Comment: @Paulie_D It looks like that list is for hosts not guest performers.

Comment: Burroughs is included so...yes, it does cover cameos etc,

Comment: @Paulie_D: I'm not seeing Burroughs on that page and a search isn't finding it there either. Also, it is not a complete list; it has a list for "five timers".

Comment: Check the alphabetical lists...he's there. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Saturday_Night_Live_guests_(A%E2%80%93D)

Comment: SNL used to have a lot more guest performers in the 70s and early 80s. Andy Kaufman was a guest performer (never a host). Harry Anderson, Penn and Teller, and Joel from MST3k were frequent guests doing magic and juggling. They've had occasional cameos of politicians. Not sure about literary guests. But just wanted to put some context around how in 1981 having a guest performer, specifically one doing a guest performance (and not just acting in a sketch), was more common than the show today.